# Does a ceiling fan need to be wired to a switch?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I'm looking to install ceiling fans and recessed lighting in the bedrooms of my house. My thought was to tie the fans into the existing outlet wiring and just have them be on constant power, controlled by remote and pull cords. The recessed lighting would use the existing lighting wiring and switch. This would mean no having to muck around with adding a separate wall switch for the fan and would simplify the job a bit, and since I don't plan to use a light kit on the fans I really see no benefit in being able to turn the fan off at a switch.

Is there anything I'm missing with this idea? I've tried searching but can't really find anything about problems with wiring a fan to a constant power source, all the instructions out there include using a switch. I feel like maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Why would you need to have it attached to a switch? Most ceiling fans come with pull chains and built in switches which control the lights (if installed) and the speed of the fan itself. One of those four speeds on the fan is an "off" speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no problem installing the fan without a switch.

In many cases folks replace a switched ceiling light fixture with a fan, so the fan uses the switch that used to control the light.   In other cases the ceiling is too high, so controlling the fan via the pull chain is inconvenient.

If you install the fan without a switch, you could always add a remote module later.  They're cheap, easy to install, and allow you to control both a fan and light.